# web.config rules to force open .vcf on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-config, vcf-vcard

Through other posts, my web.config file was modified to get most devices to open the .vcf file, but Chrome on my Android (S3) phone displays it instead.

I used vcard 2.1 and running IIS 7.5. Here's [the link.](https://www.overair.ca/bc/ethan.vcf)

I tried to fiddle with: **value="attachment; filename=(*.vcf)"**
but no luck.

Here are the outboundRules:

```
<rule name="Allow vcards to be downloaded" preCondition="Only match vcards">
    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Disposition" pattern="(.*)" negate="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="attachment, filename=(*.vcf)" replace="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^text/x-vcard" />
    </conditions>
</rule>

<preConditions>
     <preCondition name="Only match vcards">
         <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/x-vcard$" />
     </preCondition>
</preConditions>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!